# How to get status of execution of a method declared as Single Instance Mode

Tags: c#, wcf, execution, status, instancecontextmode

I have declared my service behavior as single instance mode as stated below

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)] 
public class Service : IService
{
  [OperationBehavior]
        public void DoSomething()
        {
          ...
        }
}
```

I want to know the execution status of *DoSomething()* from the client, ensuring that while it is running, no client request should call *DoSomething()*. Please help me to find a solution?

Comment: how would client know about the *execution status*

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

If you actually have only a single instance, you *could* have a second method, that gives you a status. But this is a asynchronous system, if you ask whether it's busy, you get an answer... on your next call it might already be different. You *could* return a bool from your method and make your method return false immediately if you find out it's already running. Or you could make your method *wait* for all other calls to finish and then continue with it's current call. Or you could have that message just *queue* the work and have another service continuously working on all queued items one after another.

The point is, you need a *strategy* here, and you need to make that decision. Once you have made it and you implemented it and you have a specific problem doing so, fel free to come here and ask a *specific* question again.